# 'fail to add torrent' error nexus 5

Tags: android, port, bittorrent, tor

Trying to use torrent download on nexus 5 modded rom slimkat 4.4.
Keep getting error ~ 'falied to add torrent from source target'.
Tried using utorrent and ttorrent-lite, and have not had any success. 
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  I think i have successfully forwarded tcp and udp ports, but any help in how to set that as well would be very much apprecated.
Thank you.